# Games Gish & Polynominal, the "A" key  is automatically in key-down state

Tags: 11.10

For both Gish and Polynomial - Space of the Music, the "A" key seems to be being held down. This results in Gish being completely unplayable as the leftward movement is unstoppable, so you can't do the first level, and Polynomial being nausea-inducing as there is a constant leftward roll. This does not happen with any other game (warsow, xonotic, dungeons of dredmor, oil rush, etc), just with these 2, but it's not specific to the game if it's happening on 2. Does anybody know what could be going on?

For some background, I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 amd64, with an nvidia geforce gt540m enabled using bumblebee (due to optimus).

EDIT: Managed to find my own answer: It's the gamepad inputs that seem to be doing strange things. If anybody gets the same problem, go into the controls and strip out all the gamepad/joystick inputs.

Comment: Glad you solved it, can you post your solution as an answer so we can mark it as solved? (The system will make you wait 24 hours before letting you post it. Thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

(**Answer by OP in the question**)

> Managed to find my own answer: It's the gamepad inputs that seem to be doing strange things. If anybody gets the same problem, go into the controls and strip out all the gamepad/joystick inputs.